# Problem with the use of the Thales' Theorem

Tags: geometry

Hi guys I have this problem:

Given a parallelogram $ABCD$, consider two points $P$ and $Q$ on the diagonal $AC$, such that $AP\cong QC$. Extends $DP$ up to meet $AB$ in $P'$ and $DQ$ up to meet $BC$ in $Q'$. Show that $P'Q' // AC$.

Since the diagonals of the parallelogram $AC$ and $BD$ are divided into equal parts, I know that $AO=CO$ and $BO=DO$. For hypothesis $AP=BC$, then $PO=OQ$, therefore $DPBQ$ is a parallelogram.

Whereas the triangle $Q'DP'$, since $QB//DP$, from the Thales' Theorem I have: $QD:QQ'=P'H:HQ'$. Similarly, whereas the triangle $DP'Q'$, since $PB//DQ$, I have: $PD:PP'=KQ':P'K$.

To show that $AC//P'Q'$, I would like to show that $PD:PP'=QD:QQ'$, then I would try that $KQ':P'K=P'H:HQ'$.

I have considered the triangles $QHQ'$, $BHK$ and $PKP'$, which are similar and so: $Q'H:HK:QH:BH$ and $P'K:KH=PK:KB$,

then I have: $Q'K:Q'H=QB:QH$ and $P'H:P'K=PB:PK$, but I cannot conclude. I do not know if I reasoned well or I are fooled, anyone has any idea?[image]

Comment: If DB were orthogonal to AC then P'Q' would be parallel to AC by symmetry. Shearing parallel to AC preserves that property.

Comment: Ok, but without this hypothesis as I do?

Comment: The general parallelogram can be obtained by shearing the symmetrical case parallel to AC. P'Q' will still be parallel to AC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through D draw DX // AC with DX = AP. Then, ADXP is a //gm. It should be clear that DXCQ is also a //gm because QC = AP = DX.[image]

Extend BA to cut XD produced at A’. B’ is similarly formed.

Note that A’ACD and B’CAD are also //gm. In addition, A’D = DB’ (because they both equal to AC).

From the fact that $\triangle Q’B’D \sim \triangle Q’CQ$, we have $\dfrac {Q’Q}{Q’D} = \dfrac {QC}{DB’}$.

Similarly, $\dfrac { P’P}{P’D} = \dfrac {AP}{A’D}$.

Then, $\dfrac {Q’Q}{Q’D} = \dfrac { P’P}{P’D}$. This further means $\dfrac {DQ}{DQ’} = \dfrac { DP}{DP’}$ (by simple manipulation of ratios).

With the fact that $\angle PDQ$ being the included angle, we have, $\triangle DPQ \sim \triangle DP’Q’$.

Required result follows.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was wrong to think.

Comment: By the triangles similar that I have considered $QHQ′$,$ BHK$ and $PKP′$ can I have : $QH:HB=KB:PK$ ? So I have the thesis.

Comment: @L.G.A.G. Maybe, but I think it is not quite possible. Because, for example, BH has been used in $\triangle QHQ' \sim \triangle BHK$ to form $\dfrac {QH}{HB}$, and on the other hand, BH has also been used in $\triangle BHK \sim \triangle PP'K$ to form $\dfrac {BH}{PP'}$. In combining the two ratios, we either have BH squared or have BH cancelled.

Comment: Yes, I was trying with values and not returned. Thanks.